# How do I close the OS I'm currently using so I can run it using VMWare?

Tags: windows-7, linux

Some friends just turned me on to virtualization and recommended VMWare. I'm currently running Windows 7 and would like to try running it virtually on a host Linux machine. The thing is, I'd like not to have to reinstall Windows from scratch. I'd like (if possible) to clone the state of my current Windows 7 install, make it into an ISO, and install THAT into VMWare. Is this possible, or am I high?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official, supported way to do this with VMWare is with the [VMWare vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/)

Comment: Wow. Awesome! The VMWare site is a bit heavy on businessspeak and difficult to follow, so I just want to doublecheck: to run this setup, all I'd need are the converter and the player, right? There is no need to purchase the Workstation?

Comment: It says it supports Player, so I assume all you need is the converter and the player. I've never actually had a need for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is Possible and its called P2V or Physical to Virtual Conversion in the Virtualization World and you can do it using using http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/ and best of all its free !